# How to do calculations on two carbon dates?

Tags: php, php-carbon

So I thought of `subtract` and then I tried `diffInDays`, but I am not getting the results I want, unless this makes sense.

- Date One: 2019-01-01, `$dateOne`
- Date Two: 2019-09-01, `$dateTwo`

When I do:

- `$dateOne = Carbon::parse($dateOne);`
- `$dateTwo = Carbon::parse($dateTwo);`

And then do:

`$dateOne->diffInDats($dateTwo);`

I get 245. Ok, so lets divide that by 30.5 and the answer is 7.96721311;

It should be closer to 9, if not around 9. Because from January 1st to September 1st is nine months.

The calculation is: `$dateOne - $dateTwo / 30.5`.

Calling `subtract` on $dateOne, `$dateOne->subtract($dateTwo)`gives me a Carbon error of illegal Offset type. hence why I used diff in days.

This number, after In divide by 30.5, doesn't seem right to me. Essentially is this correct for the calculation provided? **Because I think no.**

If this is correct can some one explain why? I cannot imagine 30.5 would shave off two months.

**Thoughts?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there are any issues here. Looking at the above.

- Date One: 2019-01-01, $dateOne
- Date Two: 2019-09-01, $dateTwo

So that is a difference of 245 days as you mentioned. and dividing that by 30.5

245 / 30.5 ~ 8,

There are 8 months between 1st January and 1st September, as September is not a full month here. If you set $dateTwo to 2019-09-30 you will get a value closer to 9. which is correct.